# Create table from results of ST_Intersection queries in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, attribute-table, where-clause

I create a query in PostGIS using 'where' clause, and with that a table. now I want to use those attributes to create a intersection with other table... but I don't know how to call the attributes, because is always asking for the original table and like that it will skip the query

First query to get Rail features:

```
CREATE TABLE RAIL AS
SELECT rw.gid, rw.name, rw.type, rw.geom
FROM railways rw
WHERE "type" = 'rail';
```

Here I have my new table (layer in qgis) with only the type "rails". NOw when I want to do the intersection with rivers table (layer):

```
CREATE TABLE RW_W_RESULT AS
SELECT rw.gid as rwgid, rw.name as rwname, rw.type as rwtype, w.gid as wgid, w.name as wname, w.type as wtype, 
ST_COLLECTIONEXTRACT(ST_INTERSECTION(w.geom, rw.geom),1) as rw_w_geom, 
COUNT(DISTINCT rw.gid)                      
FROM waterways w, rail 
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(w.geom, rw.geom) AND w.gid < rw.gid 
GROUP BY rw.gid,w.gid;
```

I got this error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "rw", that is clear to me, but how im suppose to call the attributes of the new created table(layer) to work with this query? If I eliminate rw. from the attributes its says is ambiguous.

Comment: This is really a fundamental SQL issue, and not anything GIS specific. If you look at the documentation, you'll find plenty of examples.  I'd recommend an explicit `JOIN` rather than an implicit one in the `FROM` list.

Comment: Once again 2/3 people who voted to close this question are ArcGIS users.

Comment: Since this is on hold, you will also need to do some work on your second query once the RAIL table is fixed as per @Micha's answer.  There is a couple of ways to do this query, here's an example of one `SELECT rw.gid, rw.name, rw.type, w.name, w.type, case when r.geom is null then 0 else 1 end AS intersects_river FROM rail rw LEFT OUTER JOIN rivers r ON ST_INTERSECTION(rw.geom, r.geom)`

Comment: No, not `ON ST_Intersection(...)`, but `ON ST_Intersects(...)`. The latter returns a Boolean, while the former returns a geometry (or geography, depending on input). Calculating the intersection is computationally expensive, so it should only be done when necessary.

Comment: @DPSSpatial. What is your point about 2/3 of people being ArcGIS users. I am very much in the open source camp and would also not have closed this question, as I think it is not just a SQL question. Are you suggesting that the review queues would be better handled by people with that area of expertise. I almost always skip reviews where the question is ArcGIS related (unless it is just obviously a totally lazy give me the codez one line question) for exactly this reason.

Comment: The error here continues to be a failure of SQL fundamentals -- Inability to recognize the "you left out the `rw` reference in the query" error from the database

Comment: @JohnBarça exactly... It drives me nuts... if it were up to me all ArcGIS questions on this forum would be closed as they belong on GeoNet.

Comment: @DPSSpatial, ouch, though I see your point.

Comment: @JohnBarça ArcGIS for Everything©

Comment: @DPSSpatial, don't get me started :-)

Comment: Alicia: as stated, you are missing the rw alias on the rail table, so where you say 'from waterways w, rail' it should be 'from waterways as w, rail as rw' (I always us as when aliasing a table) - try that out and let us know if it works. Want to get the SQL syntax correct for using the spatial functions combined with the rest of the query... Thanks!!!

Comment: Hello! I finally find the solution, I just needed to add INTO, something like this: SELECT rw.gid, rw.name, rw.type, rw.geom
INTO RAILS
FROM railways rw
WHERE "type" = 'rail';

Comment: @AliciaRijo you should be able to use the 'create table newTable as (sql goes here)' but good you got it to work with INTO... if you could post your final SQL with the SQL spatial function, that would be valuable. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a geometry column in the "rail" table in order to use any spatial functions.

```
CREATE TABLE RAIL AS
SELECT rw.gid, rw.name, rw.type, rw.geom
FROM railways rw
WHERE "type" = 'rail';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is, indeed, a fundamental SQL question.

The "alias" 'rw' created is the CREATE TABLE RAIL AS query is only valid in this specific query.

So you have to declare it again in the second query in the FROM clause

```
CREATE TABLE RW_W_RESULT AS
SELECT rw.gid as rwgid, rw.name as rwname, rw.type as rwtype, w.gid as wgid, w.name as wname, w.type as wtype, 
ST_COLLECTIONEXTRACT(ST_INTERSECTION(w.geom, rw.geom),1) as rw_w_geom, 
COUNT(DISTINCT rw.gid)                      
FROM waterways w, rail rw
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(w.geom, rw.geom) AND w.gid < rw.gid 
GROUP BY rw.gid,w.gid;
```

That should solve your problem